# Table Level Replication in Postgres using slony

Tags: database-replication, postgresql-9.5, slony

Is there any native table level replication(Pratial replication) in postgres?
If no, I want to replicate only some tables from my primary to standby using slony
Could anyone help me in doing this?
I am referring this link:"http://www.slony.info/documentation/1.2/firstdb.html"
But they are saying there will be a pgbench tool in contrib module in postgres
server.I am unable to find any, and my current server version is postgres-9.5.

Comment: Postgres 10 added native table level logical replication.

Comment: Thankyou @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

pgbench is a command in postgres that is included in the bin folder. 
If the DB doesn't exist you have skipped steps in the documentation link you provided.

```
createdb -O $PGBENCHUSER -h $MASTERHOST $MASTERDBNAME
createdb -O $PGBENCHUSER -h $SLAVEHOST $SLAVEDBNAME
pgbench -i -s 1 -U $PGBENCHUSER -h $MASTERHOST $MASTERDBNAME
```

I could not get this tutorial to fully work myself, but the tables were connected and replicated initially.